# Merge 2 branches without file removals

Tags: git, github

I have created a branch from master called, let's say, A. On the A branch I have deleted some files and made some changes to other files. Now I would like to merge A into master without the file removals. How could I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by `and made some changes to others` ? do you have another branch say B ?

Comment: i meant changes to other files in branch A, edited my question thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have a bunch of options here.  Some methods are better for some purposes, and other methods are better for other purposes.  I'm going to **guess** which one is the right one for you, but **it's a guess**.  I'm going to show you some options, but not all options.

Remember that Git is all about *commits*, not files.  Commits *hold* files—each commit has a complete snapshot of *every* file that's in that commit—but Git is *about* the commits.

Every commit has a unique hash ID, which is a big ugly string of letters and numbers.  That hash ID means *that* commit.  No other commit has this same string of letters and numbers.  These are what Git cares about—branch *names*, like `master` or `branch-A`, are for *you*, not for Git.  Git cares about the *commits*.

Once made, no commit can ever be changed.  Each one is frozen for all time.  But you *can* take a commit you've made—or some one else made, of course—and extract it to a work-area, make changes to the work-area, and then tell Git to make a new commit *from* the work-area.  In fact, that's *how* you use Git.

In the normal process of using Git, you might start with:

```
git checkout master
```

That tells Git: *Get me the commit whose hash ID is stored under my name `master`*.  Remember, the name is for you; Git cares about the hash ID.  Git takes all the frozen files from that commit, puts them in a work area—your *work-tree*—and now you can *see and use* the files, as they're no longer frozen in some internal Git-only format that Git keeps out of sight.

Now you do some work and `git add` some files and so on, and then you would typically run `git commit`.  Now it's time to observe another feature of each commit.

Every commit stores the raw hash ID of its *parent* commit.  So if you just extracted the commit identified by `master`, well, that commit has a *parent* commit, which has another parent, and so on.  If we draw these commits we'll see something like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

The commit you extracted has some big ugly hash ID `H`, which is stored under your name `master`.  That commit—the one we're calling `H`—remembers the hash ID of its *parent* commit `G`.

You've just made some changes and run `git commit`.  Git will now package up a new snapshot, of *all* files, and give it a new, unique hash ID.  We'll call that hash ID `I` for short.  New commit `I` will remember commit `H` as its parent.  Let's draw that:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
               \
                I
```

Now comes the tricky part!  Hash IDs are too hard for humans to remember, so to help us out, Git will store the hash ID of `I` under some name.  The *name* it will use is the one we gave to `git checkout`.  So Git will update our `master` to point to new commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

That's not what you wanted, though, so that's not quite what you did.  First you checked out `master`.  Then you told Git: *make me a new name, `branch-A`*.  Git did that, so now you have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, branch-A
```

To remember which one you gave to `git checkout`, Git attaches a special name, `HEAD` (in all capital letters like this), to the name you used:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, branch-A (HEAD)
```

When you then make new commit `I`, Git knows to update the name to which `HEAD` is attached.  So now you have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- branch-A (HEAD)
```

Now, I don't know how *many* commits you made on this `branch-A` branch.  I'll draw three in a moment.  But somewhere along the way you told Git: *remove some files*.  So commit snapshot `I`, or maybe `J` or `K`, or maybe all three, are *missing some file(s) completely:*

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- branch-A (HEAD)
```

You *cannot change any of these commits*.  Whichever commits lack those files, those commits *lack those files forever*.

If you haven't *given* those commits to anyone else, though, you have a great option here.  You can *forget all about those commits*.  You can make new *replacement* commits that are new and improved: they're a lot like the originals, except in the new replacements, you *don't* remove the files.

The main drawback to this option is that you have to make a replacement for each such commit.  However, there's an easy-ish way to do that.  The other main drawback to this option is the catch: **if you haven't *given* those commits to anyone else**.  Remember, Git cares about the hash IDs.  If you gave these commits to someone else, they *have* these commits, with these hash IDs, in *their* repository.

If someone else does have these commits, that's not totally fatal to the proposal here, it just means that the "someone else" might *also* have to switch away from the old commits to the new ones.  Or you might want to use a different option entirely, one that I'm not going to show here.

Anyway, let's take a look at what you have now, again.  Remember, I'm **guessing** what you have.  You're going to have to take your *own* look—I suggest running `git log --decorate --oneline --graph branch-A master` to do that—but here's my drawing again:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- branch-A (HEAD)
```

Let's say you removed files in commit `J`, or maybe `I`.  Now you want them back.  You're currently on your commit `K`, because you're still on your `branch-A`, which is why your `HEAD` is still attached to `branch-A`.

What you will do first is make yet another new commit.  It will get a new hash ID which we'll call `L` (the actual ID will be some big ugly string of letters and numbers as usual).  To make this new commit, while you have `K` out and everything is clean because it's all committed—so `git status` says "on branch branch-A, nothing to commit"—you change your work-area to *put the files back*.

Remember also that every commit has a complete snapshot of *all* of its files.  So we'll get the files back from commit `H`, which, after all, is still exactly the same as it always was—all commits are frozen in time!  We just need to *see* those files.

There are a few ways to do that.  One is to use `git show`, like this:

```
git show master:path/to/file
```

That displays the contents of `path/to/file` as saved in commit `H`—the commit to which your name `master` points—on your screen.  Of course, you don't want to *see* it, you want to save it back to `path/to/file`.  So you could do this:

```
git show master:path/to/file > path/to/file
git add path/to/file
```

There's an odd feature of `git checkout`, though.  It has a mode where it does this for us, *without* actually switching commits and/or branches.  So we can write:

```
git checkout master -- path/to/file
```

This is equivalent to the `git show`, in that it *creates or replaces* the file in our work-area, *and* to the `git add`, in that it updates the *index* just like `git add` would.

(We haven't talked about the index.  The index, which is also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, is very important in Git.  But for now I don't have time to put it into this answer.)

Anyway, after you repeat this for all the files you deleted that you should not have deleted, you can now run `git commit` to make a new snapshot:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L   <-- branch-A (HEAD)
```

Commit `L` puts the files back.

We just said that you deleted them in `J`.  You'll have to make sure which commit *did* delete them at this point, because now we're going to use a clever trick.  We can't change anything about any existing commit—`I`, `J`, `K`, and `L` all have this form forever—but we *can* extract commits, change the work-areas, and make *new* commits.  So now we'll have Git extract commit `I`, maybe make some changes, and commit again.  Then we'll have Git work with `J`, which is the one where we screwed up earlier by removing files.  We'll have Git *add* the changes from `K`, to put the files *back*, at this point, and then we'll have Git make a new commit.

We'll have Git do all this *starting from commit `H`*.  Here's what the result should look like:

```
             I'-J'-K'   <-- HEAD
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L   <-- branch-A
```

`I'` is our new copy of `I`, perhaps with a different date-stamp if nothing else.  (If we really don't need to change anything at all, we can just re-use `I` directly, and Git will figure this out for us.)  Then `J'` is our copy of `J` *but with `L`'s changes, to put the files back, added in*.  Then `K'` is our copy of `J'`.  `K'` is like `K` but its parent is `J'` and it also has the files we accidentally removed at `J`.

#### Reaching this nirvana (or whatever it may be)

To *achieve* all of this, we *run* `git rebase` with the `-i` option, telling it to copy commits from our current branch (`branch-A`), except for commits that are also on `master`, and to put the new copies after the end of `master`:

```
git rebase -i master
```

Git looks at our graph:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L   <-- branch-A (HEAD)
```

and sees that there are four commits that are *only* on `branch-A` here.  (Commits `F-G-H` are on `branch-A`, but they're on `master` too.)  So Git will now make up a list of work to do:

```
pick <hash-of-I> <subject-line-from-I>
pick <hash-of-J> <subject-line-from-J>
pick <hash-of-K> <subject-line-from-K>
pick <hash-of-L> <subject-line-from-L>
```

Git will open your chosen editor—the same one you chose for making commit messages—on a file with these instructions in it.  Your job is to *modify* the instructions and write out the modified instructions and exit the editor.

Since commit `J` is where we screwed up by removing files, what we want to do is to have Git *fix up* `J` by *adding* `L` to it.  So we re-arrange the work list, moving `L` to just after `J`:

```
pick <hash-of-I> <subject-line-from-I>
pick <hash-of-J> <subject-line-from-J>
pick <hash-of-L> <subject-line-from-L>
pick <hash-of-K> <subject-line-from-K>
```

Then we change the word `pick` on the line about commit `L` to the word `fixup`.  (You can use the word `squash` here instead if you like—these are almost the same thing, and if this were a proper tutorial, we'd go through squashing here first, but in this particular case you'll want `fixup`).

If the mistake was at `I`, we put the `fixup` using `L` right after the line about picking commit `I`.  If the mistake was at `L`, we leave the lines in their original order and just change the last `pick` to `fixup`.  The idea here is that commit `L`—the one that puts the files *back*—is the *fix* for the commit that broke things by *removing* the files in the first place.

In any case, we have now used our editor on this instruction sheet.  We've finished updating the instructions, so we write out the sheet and exit the editor.  Git now *executes the instructions*, giving us:

```
             I'-J'-K'   <-- HEAD
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L   <-- branch-A
```

(The name `HEAD` is temporarily *detached* from any branch name, during the picking and fixing-up process.)

If all goes well, the very last step of this rebase process happens now.  Git takes the *name* `branch-A`, which is Git's way of remembering a commit hash ID for us, off commit `L`.  It attaches the branch name to the *last commit copied or fixed-up*, which in this case is commit `K'`.  Then it re-attaches our `HEAD`.  So now we have this:

```
             I'-J'-K'   <-- branch-A (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K--L   [abandoned]
```

We don't need original commits `I-J-K-L` any more.  They have been replaced with shiny new commits `I'-J'-K'`.  The *name* `branch-A` remembers `K'` for us.  If we run `git log`, it *looks like* we somehow changed the bad commits to good ones.

We didn't—the original commits are all still there—but we're the only person who knows that `branch-A` used to identify the bad commits, and we have the only Git repository that *has* the bad commits.  We never give them to anyone else so as far as the rest of the universe is concerned, they don't even exist.

Now we have *good* commits, and we can do our merge the way we would do it if we'd never made the mistake in the first place.

Comment: godlike answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. `git checkout -- <file>... to discard changes in working directory`
2. `git add <fileName>` or `git add .`(for all the changes in current directory) to add the file to commit.
3. `git commit -m "Your message"`
4. `git push origin master` to push the changes to master

Comment: I believe you don't want to keep that deleted files in your branch A.

Comment: i cannot discard changes with git checkout because the file are being deleted during merge

Comment: you can use `git revert commitid` for that commit. Have you committed other changes  as well with this commit ?